# How to find average in mongoose aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am aggregating data from 3 collections - 
Users -

```
 [
{
"_id": "5bc425bb3e99c8269ce51faa",
"fname": "Akash",
"salary": 25000,
"age": 23,
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5bc425e23e99c8269ce51fab",
"fname": "Aditya",
"salary": 20000,
"age": 28,
"__v": 0
}
]
```

Balance -

```
[
{
"_id": "5bc4349adcc885e047054466",
"fname": "Akash",
"balance": 4000
},
{
"_id": "5bc434ffdcc885e0470544c2",
"fname": "Aditya",
"balance": 8000
}
]
```

dept collection -

```
[
{
"_id": "5bc46167b365918881aa3bbf",
"fname": "Akash",
"dept": "IT"
},
{
"_id": "5bc4620fb365918881aa3c1b",
"fname": "Apurva",
"dept": "Chemical"
}
]
```

I want to aggregriated result as -

```
[
{
"_id": {
"fname": "Aditya",
"balance": 8000,
"dept": "Medical",
"salary": 20000
},
"avg": 20000
},
{
"_id": {
"fname": "Apurva",
"balance": 1000,
"dept": "Chemical",
"salary": 22000
},
"avg": 22000
}
]
```

My query  -

```
User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "balance",
        localField: "fname",
        foreignField: "fname",
        as: "result"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$result"
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "dept",
        localField: "fname",
        foreignField: "fname",
        as: "deptresult"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$deptresult"
    },
    { $sort: { salary: -1 } },
    // { $limit: 1 },
    {
      $project: {
        fname: 1,
        salary: 1,
        "result.balance": 1,
        "deptresult.dept": 1,
        avg: { $avg: "$salary" }
      }
    }
```

It shows remaining result but it does now display calculated average.
Instead of average , it simply prints salary . Please someone guide me on this.
I am using mongoose ORM.Rest of the code is running fine.

Comment: Please don't post same question again and again. Reply on the same thread you will definitely get your answer. BTW you need to make another api call to get the `$avg` salary or you can use `$facet` aggregation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find average on aggregated collections using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828570/find-average-on-aggregated-collections-using-mongoose)

Comment: yep, it worked using $facet, thanks @Anthony Winzlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
User.aggregate([
 { "$facet": {
   "projection": [
     { "$lookup": {
       "from": "balance",
       "localField": "fname",
       "foreignField": "fname",
       "as": "result"
     }},
     { "$lookup": {
       "from": "dept",
       "localField": "fname",
       "foreignField": "fname",
       "as": "deptresult"
     }},
     { "$unwind": "$deptresult" },
     { "$unwind": "$result" },
     { "$sort": { salary: -1 } },
     { "$project": {
       "fname": 1,
       "salary": 1,
       "result.balance": 1,
       "deptresult.dept": 1
     }}
   ],
   "averageSalary": [
     { "$group": {
       "_id": null,
       "avg": { "$avg": "$salary" }
     }}
   ]
 }}
])
```